# Promise chaining error won’t pass into catch correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, modal-dialog, es6-promise

Here is my code:

```
// promise chain being run onClick
function clickSequence(paramObj) {
    checkForDuplicateNums(paramObj)
        .then(() => {
            checkForDuplicateEmails(paramObj);
        })
        .then(() => {
            insertReservationForm(paramObj);
        })
        .then(() => {
            sendEmail(paramObj);
        })
        .then(() => {
            updateResBtnCounter(paramObj);
        })
        .then((pageUrl) => {
            goToPage(pageUrl);
        });
        .catch((err) => {
            displayErrorMsg(err);
        })
}

// display sweet alert 2 modal
function displayErrorMsg(err) {
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'error',
        icon: 'error',
        text: `${err}`
    });
}

// checking for duplicate numbers in DB
function checkForDuplicateNums(paramObj) {
    console.log('checkforduplicatenums');
    const { campaignId, numberInputValue, errorMsg } = paramObj;
    functionName = "checkForDuplicatesNums";

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./includes/ajax_general_utilities.php",
            data: {
                functionName,
                campaignId,
                numberInputValue,
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(resp) {
                if (resp === 'true') {
                    reject(new Error(`${errorMsg}`));
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            },
            error: function(err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }); // close ajax
    }); // close promise
}

// checking for duplicate emails in DB
function checkForDuplicateEmails(paramObj) {
    const { emailInputValue, campaignId, errorMsg } = paramObj;
    functionName = "checkForDuplicateEmails";
    
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./includes/ajax_general_utilities.php",
            data: {
                functionName,
                campaignId,
                emailInputValue
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function (resp) {
                if (resp === 'true') {
                    reject(new Error(`${errorMsg}`));
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }

            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            }
        }); // close ajax
    }); // close promise
}
```

I'm trying to chain a bunch of functions together where I wrapped an ajax call in a promise.  `checkForDuplicateEmails` and `checkForDuplicateNums` check the database for duplicate values and if they find a duplicate, they call `reject()`.  I'm then passing an error message to a function name `displayErrorMessage` in the catch block that displays a `sweet alert 2` modal.

I was testing each one individually to make sure they're working correctly but I'm running into an issue.  I hardcoded values that I know are already in the database to make sure `reject()` is called.  When I comment out all except the first function `checkForDuplicateNums` the error is thrown and it is correctly passed to `displayErrorMsg` and a modal pops up.  If I uncomment out the first `.then()` call and change it so `checkForDuplicateNums` is resolved, instead of `checkForDuplicateEmails` displaying the error message correctly as a modal, I only get an error in the console that looks like:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: <then it displays error message only in console>
    at Object.success (<page url>:231)
    at c (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js:2)
```

I'm not sure why the modal will pop up only when the first function is called and not after that, I assume I'm not using promises quite right, but I can't seem to find an answer specific to my situation from searching around online.

Comment: Missing a `return` in each of those `then()` that has a function that returns another promise

Comment: That solved it!  Thank you I never would have figured out that was the problem.  I thought it implicitly returned in that situation - I'll have to do some more reading on returns in es6.

Comment: No implicit return and without those promise returns the `then()` chain will complete before all those function promises will